# Can you use Google Maps offline, with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I use OpenLayers, GeoServer and PostGIS in my application. Is it possible to have Google maps offline? No need to connect to internet to get it. I'm working to make my app working offline only for security matters.

If not, then what do you recommend me to replace it with?

Comment: Offline: Do mean a intranet only, app?

Comment: my app should never connect to internet. and since I use Google API to display base map currently. I need to find a way to use it offline or replace it with another service.

Comment: You can only use the Android Google Maps App to cache maps offine - it is limited to 5 areas of interest and zoom levels. OSM would be a better solution. Nokia Maps downloads entire countries.

Comment: Can I use the android offline maps for any web application?

Answer (score 2):

Google will sell you a map server appliance for local use, but I am reliably informed it is expensive.

A better alternative is open street map. A local install on an Ubuntu box with apache and [mapnik](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik) is [easy and cheap](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

Comment: but mapnik doesnt have OSM data loaded.

Comment: @Krystian: the openstreetmap site uses mapnik. updated links to show this.

Comment: do I have to use mapnik even I use GeoServer?

Comment: Something has to generate the maps (rendering tiles from the OSM vector data). That something is (usually) mapnik. You can choose to load the maps into geoserver, but its usually better to use apache and mod_tile for the maps, and to just use geoserver for your vector overlay data.

Comment: Ok, just one more question plz, which one of options is the best for my case? http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/

Comment: it always depends..if you think about basemap I suggest you to use it in raster format because of performance and there is no need to use vectors in this case (because of it is a background for your actual layers). geoserver can serve rasters to, so IMO if you have installed geoserver you don't have reasons install secound simillar software (I mean mapnik) but if you want to you can. In that case you would serve raster (basemap) data from mapnik and vector layer data from geoserver. But as I said before it would be software overgrowth for me.

Comment: @Noon I suggest doing it from packages

Comment: @Krystian: Can you explain where the rasters would come from in your proposed design?

Comment: @BradHards rasters would be served from db - postgreSQL via geoserver service (for ex. RESTful service) serving rasters from db its more fast than gathering tiles from files. I show my solution to simillar problem here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/geoserver-best-way-to-publish-2500-tiff-or-71-ecw-files/

Comment: @Krystian What about the performance, is it acceptable? OSM seems quite heavy.

Comment: @Krystian: What are you proposing as the source of rasters (i.e. where would you import them from, given that there is potentially a need for world-wide coverage). Perhaps Shadin can explain his coverage needs though.

Comment: yes, the most important question should be how big is area? All my above examples was based on my own experience where I had to show area of ~454085ha which was covered by 82 ortophotomaps. I don't know if it will works in such way for whole World, because as you were saying data is quite heavy, and you need very good hardware to performe this kind of task.

Comment: @BradHards you can import data for particular towns/countries from OSM for ex., or use ortophotomaps from your national surveying service. If you tests few size of tiles you will find the size which are you looking for. Because if you create too tiny tiles you will have to do a lot of requests from server, but if yours tiles will be to big you will have to wait for downloading them from server. So you should find a 'happy medium' between geometric size of tile and its size of file.

Comment: OSM tiles are always rendered at 256x256. Since I've done this, you need to be trying to help the original poster, not me. I'm just trying to get you to expand your (somewhat "hand-wavy") answers so that they are more useful.

Comment: @BradHards yeah, if we are talking about OSM (without postprocessing) you have right, but I mentioned before, that you can use all kind of data that you want. So I gave more wide answer. I don't like to show exact codes samples/snippets in such case because problem is too complex and showing it step-by-step would be pointless. So I think, that its better to show general idea of solution rather then actual pieces of code. IMO tutorials are for this kind of thing, and everyone can find it, especially in open source projects.

Answer (score 1):

if you want do develope application without Internet connection I suggest you to use [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/). You can share geographic data trought it and openlayers works great with it too! but the most disadvantage of it is that you have to care about geographic data by your own.

Comment: I already use geoserver to display my data over the base map. but the base map itself is google map so I'm looking for something would work offline instead of it.

Comment: as I wrote before you have gain basemap by your own in raster format. The answer depends on how big your area data is? There are many sites where you can download vector geographic data for free and then serve its by WMS or other raster service. This is solution to your problem - you can use basemap from some server (for ex. via Google API) or load data to your local server and share it via network without having Internet connection. There is no other posibility.

Comment: ok, so how can I load a base map on my local server without internet? from what I understand this is impossible with Google API.

Comment: change google api to other framework (for ex. openlayers http://openlayers.org) then you have to have your data in raster format -> connect it to geoserver (via files or by DB) and voila! you may create tiles from your raster and raster pyramids to increase performance. I would suggest you to use REST services other than WMS services to use with your basemap it is much much faster than WMS. :)

Comment: The original poster said he uses openlayers already.

Comment: @BradHards so everything should works just perfect. :)

Comment: @Krystian thanks a lot. but since I'm a quite beginner I need some more explanation on how to do that. please

Comment: would openlayers offer a base maps of the whole world ?