# How to serve a Geoserver ECW mosaic

Tags: geoserver, mosaic, ecw

I've recently setup Geoserver with GDAL/ECW support. I can create a store in Geoserver which allows me to reference one .ecw file. I can serve this one file over WMS and it works great.

Now i need to serve all 1700 .ecw files as a single layer. I believe this is a function of the ImageMosaic option. However it only seems to allow me to attach one file.

Is there some preparation I need to do to the 1700 files to be able to use them as an ImageMosaic?

[image]

Comment: Is it expecting a tileset, like the one that GDAL2Tiles http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html generates?

Comment: No, it does not expect tileset http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html.

Comment: 1700 files may be too many, you might need a pyramid. Also you will need a licence to use the ECW code on a server

Comment: This is almost the same as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/geoserver-best-way-to-publish-2500-tiff-or-71-ecw-files?rq=1

Comment: The issue was actually a permissions problem. The folder could not be read by the application user. Thanks for all the comments.